# Removing Protrusion from A circle and Erode Radius

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Please anybody tell me how to remove only the protrusion from this image using just the morphological operations. Also I want to reduce the circle (white color) radius by 5 pixels. I know we can do that by using erosion but what should be the structuring element's(disk type) radius should be and how many iterations should we perform for the selected radius.

I mean can we have structuring element se =strel('disk',5) and perform one iteration or se = strel('disk',1) and perform 5 iterations.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to note for those who want the hold, there are two good answers, one already accepted

Comment: I removed the OpenCV tag as your attempts to solve your problem do not use that library.

Comment: Ok...but my question is just not limited to Matlab....its open to opencv as well but no body answered...I am working in opencv just for your information..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab has a simple function for you to do this. You can use a [morphological open operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) and [morphological erode operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html?refresh=true) to achieve this. The code can be found below.

```
I = imread( 'O3Z7j.jpg' );
figure; imshow( I )
D = imopen(I,strel( 'disk', 50 ) );
figure; imshow( D )
E = imerode(D,strel( 'disk', 5 ) );
figure; imshow( E )
```

Essentially as Wiki describes it, [morphological open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_%28morphology%29) is the "dilation of the erosion of a set A", where [erosion is defined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)). To create the structuring element kernel, you can use `strel( 'disk', n )` to define a disc of radius `n`.

The result is shown here.

[image]

Here is the image before the erosion.

[image]

The before image is shown here.

[image]

**EDIT**: Performance

```
>> sum( sum( I>128 ) )
ans =
      227675
>> sum( sum( D>128 ) )
ans =
      227173
>> 227675 - 227173
ans =
   502
```

**EDIT 2:** Added imerode for new requirement.

Comment: Please tell me how many pixels will be removed from the disk i.e white portion using your structuring element of radius 50 in one iteration. Thanks

Comment: @Navdeep Added performance, it seems to have removed about 502 px. I don't have the perfect original image, so it's only approximate.

Comment: Actually I want to remove 5 pixels from the disk I. e I want to reduce the radius of the disk by 5 pixels. How can we do that?

Comment: @Navdeep After performing the `imopen` in my code, you can do an `imerode` as you originally did. I'll edit your question and my answer accordingly in a bit.

Comment: @Navdeep Actually can you append that to your question? The "removing 5 pixels from the disk" part

Answer (score 5):

Assume your image is in a `BW` array, you can find the center of the main disk with `bwdist` and then find the pixels that are anormally distributed with respect to the distance to the center.

In practice, this gives:

```
tol = 25;

% --- Get the center
D = bwdist(1-BW);
[~,I] = max(D(:));
[y, x] = ind2sub(size(BW), I);

% --- Find distances
[Y, X] = find(BW);
J = find(BW);
[d2, K] = sort((X-x).^2 + (Y-y).^2);
z = 1:numel(d2);

f = fit(z', d2, 'poly1');
I = (d2 > z'*f.p1 + f.p2 + tol);

BW(J(K(I))) = 0;
```

and the result:

[image]

You can tune the parameter `tol` to erode more or less the protrusion, but it should not be below 20 otherwise you with remove pixels of the main disk.

Best,

Comment: Personally I prefer my answer instead, it's more elegant, logical, and is probably faster :/ It's also used in industry for image processing and complements erosion/dilation/closing operations that OP described.

Comment: @krisdestruction I suspect Ratbert took this route because the most standard way was to perform morphological operations and you already provided a viewpoint with your answer.  This route is certainly another way to think about it, and I appreciate the effort.  It's something I would have never considered. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng definitely and I've used this way before too, but there's a lot of hardcoding. I also +1'd it as an alt approach

Comment: @Ratbert the OP specified a new requirement